# Cant get properly the ResultSet from SQL execution

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, resultset

I have some db I created for school with Tasks. Each Task record have username, description, taskday, taskhour columns.

I want to pull the records by two values: taskhour and taskday or each one individually.

So I have a function that get a task object and check if the taskday or taskhour are empty and prepare the query accordingly. But from some reason something is wrong with the ResultSet...this is my function:

```
public List<Task> getUserTasks(Task task) throws SQLException {

    List<Task> listOfTasks = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

         String query = "";
         PreparedStatement pStatement;

        if (task.getDay() != 0 && task.getHour() != 0) {
            query = "select * from TASKS where USERNAME=? and TASKDAY=? and TASKHOUR=?";
            pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pStatement.setString(1, task.getUsername());
            pStatement.setInt(2, task.getDay());
            pStatement.setInt(3, task.getHour());

        } else if (task.getDay() == 0) {
            query = "select * from TASKS where USERNAME=? and TASKHOUR=?";
            pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pStatement.setString(1, task.getUsername());
            pStatement.setInt(2, task.getHour());

        } else {
            query = "select * from TASKS where USERNAME=? and TASKDAY=?";
            pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pStatement.setString(1, task.getUsername());
            pStatement.setInt(2, task.getDay());
        }


        ResultSet rs;
        rs = pStatement.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            Task taskToAdd = new Task();

            taskToAdd.setUsername(rs.getString("USERNAME"));
            taskToAdd.setDescription(rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"));
            taskToAdd.setDay(rs.getInt("TASKDAY"));
            taskToAdd.setHour(rs.getInt("TASKHOUR"));

            listOfTasks.add(taskToAdd);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listOfTasks;      
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

thanks!

Comment: "...something is wrong with the ResultSet..." You’ll have to be more specific than that. *What* is wrong with the ResultSet?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the ArrayList being returned contains at most one row. I suspect you want **`while (rs.next())`**. Use `while` to form a loop, so the actions are repeated, until there are no more rows to retrieve. (I still stand by all of the suggestions in my previous answer, especially closing the statement in a `finally` block.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want to return more than one row from the resultset?

To get *all* of the rows use **`while`** not **`if`**:

```
 while (rs.next())
 ^^^^^
```

The `while` forms a loop, which will be repeated until the expression `rs.next()` no longer evaluates to true.

The `if` is only performed once. You'll get back at most one row.

Answer (score 0):

After the `if else` block that sets $query, the code next sets $query again. Wiping out the work that was just done in the `if else` block.

As a starter, remove the seven lines immediately preceding this line:

```
ResultSet rs;
```

---

**UPDATE**

The specification says "check if the taskday or taskhour" are empty.

The conditional test ( `!= 0` ) is checking for inequality to zero.

It's not clear to me that "inequality to zero" is what is meant by "empty".

What we don't see is what type is returned by the `getDay` and `getHour` methods. From the code, it looks like they are returning `int` primitives. (Given that there's no test for null, and the comparison is to an integer literal.) But that's just an assumption; I don't have a way of checking.

I would typically include parens around the inequality comparisons.

```
if ( ( task.getDay() != 0 ) && ( task.getHour() != 0 ) )  {
     ^                    ^    ^                     ^
```

I don't think the extra parens are required in Java. But I'm fairly certain that aren't illegal. But I'm not really a Java guy.  (When I include extra parens like that, that takes care of operator precedence for me. (I don't have to remember which operator has a higher precedence.)

Also, the SELECT statement is doing a `SELECT *`. I would explicitly list the columns to be returned, rather than use `*`. For example:

```
 SELECT t.USERNAME, t.DESCRIPTION, t.TASKDAY, t.TASKHOUR FROM TASKS t ...
```

But I don't really think that's the cause of your issue.

I am bothered that there isn't a `finally` block that closes the statement.

```
} finally {
    if (pStatement != null) { pStatement.close(); }
}
```

Also, I would assign the return `getDay()` and `getHour()` to local variables. I'd do that just once, on entering the method.

And then I'd reference the local variables in the conditional tests, and as arguments in the methods to do the binds to the prepared statement.

But again, I don't think there's anything specifically illegal about the way you've got it written.

---

For debugging, I would ignore the values returned from getDay() and getHour(), and do an assignment of specific literals to the local variables. I would do that to work through all of the logic.

Aside from those comments, I can't really debug your program for you.

[**How to debug small programs** http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: sorry, thos lined after the if/else was not suppose to be there, edited the code. this is not the problem..